# ClassNotFoundException while Deploying Application on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` while deploying my application on the Tomcat. The class is in the package without any compilation errors. This class actually initializes the application. I have cleaned the project, updated Maven dependencies but no affect. Deployment Assembly has been configured to put all the jars in Web/Inf/lib folder. I am not sure what is causing this error.

Stack trace:

```
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.2.3-bin\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.2.3-bin\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;;C:\Dev\sts-3.6.1.RELEASE;;.
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:VINUISupportApp' did not find a matching property.
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 805 ms
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 25, 2016 9:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Dev\EIS_V5\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\VINUISupportApp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class mig.vinadmin.StartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mig.vinadmin.StartupListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/EISSupportTools] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 25, 2016 9:46:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6879 ms
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Have you got an unbound jre6 library in the Build Path of the project ?

Comment: No, I am using Jdk7.

Comment: I am not sure about this exception, I think you should check if your jariles existing in deployment assembly, Go to-> Right click on project -> Properties -> DeploymenetAssembly and verify if your `Web/Inf/lib` listed or not. I know already did that based on your statement `Deployment Assembly has been configured to put all the jars in Web/Inf/lib folder` but double check

Comment: I've done that so many time but still same issue.

Comment: It's working now. I was updating the Maven every time I cleaned and built the project and I guess I am not suppose to update Maven all the times because it does something that Eclipse doesn't like. Now the application has been deployed.